# how to run a C file and various files associated with that(makefile, .h ,.c)?

Tags: gcc

I have to make a C program to solve `hungarian method` for Assignment problem.
So I downloaded a reference from web ,having (`makefile,test.c,hungarian.c,hangarian.h,readme ,`) ,,
Now I successfully run `test.c` by `$ make test` ,,
but I am having trouble running `hangarian.c` ,when I tried to compile this on my terminal I got::

```
anupam@JAZZ:~/Downloads/hungarian$ make hungarian
gcc -L. -lhungarian  hungarian.o   -o hungarian
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hungarian] Error 1
```

I am not getting what this error means??

Comment: I think you should have a look into `readme` file.

Comment: @G_P I have already seen there is no information about this,,it was just about the objective of this program.

Comment: This seems to be offtopic because it is about C programming.

Comment: sure,it is about C,, but I think the errors are related to gcc and there is a notion of /usr/bin/ld : so I thought it may be related to ubuntu..

Comment: Where can we get the original files to try to help you ?

Comment: hungarian.c have main function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Google-fu found the source files you are trying to compile:

http://robotics.stanford.edu/~gerkey/tools/hungarian.html

and in particular:

http://robotics.stanford.edu/~gerkey/tools/libhungarian-0.3.tar.gz

Simply running `make` you can build **all** the things that have to be compiled (`make hungarian` is the wrong command).

Output of `make` process:

```
gcc -O3 -Wall -I. -c hungarian.c
hungarian.c: In function ‘hungarian_routine_two’:
hungarian.c:432:14: warning: variable ‘newsum’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int oldsum,newsum;
              ^
gcc -O3 -Wall -I.   -c -o makeprob.o makeprob.c
ar cr libhungarian.a hungarian.o makeprob.o
gcc -O3 -Wall -I. -o test test.c -L. -lhungarian
gcc -O3 -Wall -I. -o timetest timetest.c -L. -lhungarian -lm
```

Now you have two executable files (`test` and `timetest`) and one static library file (`libhungarian.a`).

To run the test programs:

`./test`

`./runtest`

If you want to write a program that uses this library, you need to `#include "hungarian.h"` in your `myprogram.c` file, and to compile it with a command similar to those of the test programs:

`gcc -O3 -Wall -I. -o myprogram myprogram.c -L. -lhungarian`

I suggest you to make a copy of `test.c` (`cp test.c myprogram.c`) and modify it to fit your needs.

As you can see, there's some magic happening here: `man` pages of `make` and `gcc` should shed some rays of light on it.